# after clearing cookies else part URL not working in sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

```
public function userLogin($username, $password)
{
  $db = getDB();
  $stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT e_members.uid 
    FROM e_members
    INNER JOIN  orders ON e_members.uid = orders.uid_fk 
    WHERE  
      member_username=:member_username and 
      member_password=:member_password
  ");

  $stmt->bindParam("member_username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam("member_password", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
  $stmt->execute();

  $db = null;
  $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

  $_SESSION['session_uid'] = $data->uid;
  return $data;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
require 'class/paypalExpress.php';

if (!empty($_POST['loginSubmit']))
{
  $usernameEmail = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if(strlen(trim($usernameEmail))>1 && strlen(trim($password))>1 )
  {
    $paypalExpress = new paypalExpress();
    $uid=$paypalExpress->userLogin($usernameEmail,$password);
       
    if(isset($_SESSION['session_uid']))
    {
      $url = 'authorized web apps folder';
      header("Location: $url"); // Page redirecting to home.php
    }
    else
    {
      $url = 'home.php';
      header("Location: $url");
    }
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>PayPal Express Checkout using PHP</title>`enter code here`
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>PHP PayPal Express Checkout Demo</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" required value="" name="username" placeholder="username" class="input" />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" required value="" name="password" placeholder="password" class="input" />
      <div>
        <input type="submit" class="wallButton" value=" Log In" name="loginSubmit" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <?php echo $errorMsgLogin ?>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My select query with public function in prepare and index pages are above.

I want to check if two table IDs are equal. If they are equal, go to `if` part, otherwise `else` part. But the `else` part URL is not working. Once the `if` part login details are given it works, and after that the `else` part works. But after I clear cookies the `else` part login details won't work.

Comment: The link between a browser and the server-side session is maintained via a Session Cookie stored in the browser for the duration of the active session. Clearing cookies will remove the link between the browser and the server-side session. So therefore, effectively in that situation you start a new session. Of course if the session is new, then any existing $_SESSION variables will not be available. Your description of the behaviour of the program and all the `if`s and `else`s is very unclear, but the fact you mention cookies makes me think this is the issue.

Comment: P.S. Please don't store passwords in plain text - that is a security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.